# Editing a QVector with

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qlabel, qvector

So I am trying to create a simple program that allows me to manipulate a vector using a random function, but I feel that I am forgetting something fairly important & fundamental
please feel free to look at the code I have posted & let me know what the solution is. The error I receive is that myvec is "index out of range which only means that the pushback didn't work in the insert method that I created. Not sure why, I am still a novice.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>

QVector<QString> myvec;

void insert(QVector<QString> vec);

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::insert(QVector<QString> vec){
    vec.push_back("Hello World");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    insert(myvec);
    ui->label->setText(myvec.at(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function

```
void MainWindow::insert(QVector<QString> vec){
    vec.push_back("Hello World");
}
```

takes the vector *by value*. This means that when it's called, the argument is *copied* for use in the function, and when you modify the value there, it's not reflected on the instance *outside* of the function call (because the modification was done on the *copy*).

You want to pass the vector *by reference* so it's not copied, and modifications are done on the object which still lives *outside* the function call. This is done by adding `&` in the signature:

```
void MainWindow::insert(QVector<QString> & vec){
    vec.push_back("Hello World");
}
```

Note that you can also pass *by const reference*, which is often done for efficiency reasons. That means only a reference is passed to the function, but it isn't allowed to modify the instance within the function body.